# Offset of element - inline - using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following row:

```
<tr ng-click="show()" ng-repeat="lim in limit">
```

I need to get the **offset** (i will need Top and Left in px) of this **tr**.

Is there a way to get the offset in the controller? (either by passing some sort of parameter to function **show()** or any different way ).

So far I tried passing **$event** in **show($event)** and getting **$event.pageX and $event.pageY** but that is not what I need, i need the offset of the element itself.

Comment: Event has a target property I believe, from which you get a reference to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the **element** of the click event in this case the td from the **$event.target** property so I would pass in **$event** and then get the offset from this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6y0L28kp/

```
$scope.show = function(e){
    var offset = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(offset);
}
```